# in Android ADIF is not supported , what is ADIF , When it needed

Tags: java, android, audio, encode, aac

Friends help me please, in android media supported types, `ADIF is not supported`, what is `ADIF`, when it's used?
Is `aac` format supported for all android phones, my min sdk is `21`, asking this because in Huawei (model can't remember) file recorded in `AMR_WB` can not be played with players.

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(recFile.getPath());
mediaRecorder.prepare();
mediaRecorder.start();
```

[image]

Comment: Please take the tour stackoverflow.com/tour,  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, especially look out for hints on formatting.

Comment: So you have a `.3gp` output file that contains the `amr-wb` audio?

Answer (score 0):

when we record the audio  that is stored in different type of format output.The media codec is different from each Android-powered device.

The output format is  device-specific(based on Encoder/Decoder).

Some formats not supported  in Android media framework  [Supported Media Formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html)